How to Add Custom Actions to Jetpack Compose Selection Container?
I'm developing an Android app to display poem verses using Jetpack Compose. I want to implement a feature that allows the user to select text and show options like Share, Highlight, and Copy. However, the SelectionContainer in Jetpack Compose only provides the copy option by default.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
@Composable
fun PoemVerse() {
    SelectionContainer {
        Text(text = "This is a sample verse from a poem.")
    }
}

I couldn't find any documentation or examples on how to add custom actions to the selection menu. How can I add options like Share and Highlight to the SelectionContainer in Jetpack Compose?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Does this answer your question? It also works for text selected with SelectionContainer: Floating toolbar for text selection Jetpack Compose

The work around for me when I migrate my codebase to Kotlin and jetpack compose is to use the AndroidView composables as follow:
val textView = TextView(LocalContext.current)
textView.setIsTextSelectable(true)

textView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback = ActionModes.Callback(object : {
/**OVERRIDE THE NECESSARY METHODS*/})

